# Parameter Pentaho Report Designer with MDX

Tags: mdx, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am doing a report, using Pentaho Report Designer. My datasource is a Mondrian Cube with MySQL JDBC. I am using MDX queries, and I want to put paramerize it. I have to configure a parameter with its own query.

I'm having trouble relating the main query and the parameter query. For that, I am using the function parameter in this way:  where (strToMember(Parameter(name,type,default_value))) but it doesn´t work. What is the mistake? What do I have to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your MDX query?  And what error do you get?

The param name needs quotation marks surrounding it, i.e.

"MDXDate"

Alternatively you can just use `${paramname}`, but the disadvantage of that is you won't be able to use the preview option.

Comment: My mdx query is: select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[realizados]} ON COLUMNS,NON EMPTY [dactivo.jactivo].[All dactivo.jactivos].Children ON ROWS from [Ctrabajo] where (strToMember(Parameter("Sequipo", STRING, "[dequipo.jequipo].[All dequipo.jequipos].[1]"))) and Squipo is the next mdx query: select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[realizados]} ON COLUMNS,  NON EMPTY [dequipo.jequipo].[All dequipo.jequipos].Children ON ROWS from [Ctrabajo].When I execute, Pentaho doesn´t give me any mistake but when I choose a value for the "equipo" parameter, the report desapears, like when values are wrong or don´t exist.Thx